# Is there any official Lore on Keraptis the Wizard, apart from what is in White Plume Mountain?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, lore, adnd-2e, tales-from-the-yawning-portal

In the 5E release of ***Tales from the Yawning Portal*** there is the Module ***White Plume Mountain***.

On page 95 it states the previous lore of Keraptis the Wizard:

> Thirteen hundred years ago, the wizard Keraptis was searching for a suitable haven where he could indulge his eccentricities without fear of interference. He visited White Plume Mountain, going closer than most dared to and discovered the system of old lava-tubes that riddle the cone and the underlying strata. 
>   With a little alteration, he thought, these would be perfect for his purposes. The area already had a bad reputation, and he could think of a few ways to make it worse. So he disappeared below White Plume Mountain and vanished from the knowledge of the surface world.

Is there any more offical Lore from Wizards of the Coast, or Module writers or approved Authors on Keraptis the Wizard, or is this all there is?

Comment: [*Wikipedia* lists several ancillary sources of more information on White Plume Mountain's most famous inhabitant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Plume_Mountain) What kind of information would a good answer contain? How long are you expecting a good answer to be?

Comment: Good Points. Ideally I would be looking at something similar to the various Fandom Wiki's for various D&D settings. The issue that I have is the sources listed on the Wiki page are either separate books, or the links lead to dead pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Greyhawk Wiki has [a good article on Keraptis](https://greyhawkonline.com/greyhawkwiki/index.php?title=Keraptis).

The article cites four canon sources:

- The original  *White Plume Mountain* (1979), currently available at DriveThruRPG [as a PDF](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17064/S2-White-Plume-Mountain-1e?affiliate_id=10748) for $4.24
- *Return to White Plume Mountain* (1999), currently available at Dungeon Masters Guild [in PDF](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17404/Return-to-White-Plume-Mountain-2e) for $4.24
- Dungeon #77's *Ex Keraptis Cum Amore* (1999), out of print but available [at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Dungeon_Magazine_076)
- Dragon #241's *Arcane Lore: Greyhawk Grimoires II* (1999)

However, it's likely that the article summarizes all the main lore contained in those sources.

The article also cites other sources from the Greyhawk fan community, but these are likely to be non-canonical.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148252/40971) notes two Adventurer's League season 6 modules from 2017 which mention Keraptis, and aren't currently referenced in the Greyhawk wiki article.

Answer (score 6):

Dungeon Magazine #77 has the adventure **Ex Keraptis Cum Amore** (From Keraptis, with Love), which continues after **White Plume Mountain**.

I don't know much about it's content, but if Keraptis is in the title, there's probably some stuff about him in it.

Comment: Would you happen to know where one could acquire the adventure or the magazine?

Answer (score 2):

[Adventurers League Season 6](http://dndadventurersleague.org/storyline-seasons/the-yawning-portal/) also contained two adventures that expanded on Keraptis:

- DDAL06-02 The Redemption of Kelvan
- DDEP06-02 Return to White Plume Mountain